# Is there a way to get the ddl statement output of the Cx_Oracle.cursor.execute()'s statement execution?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am trying to create a table like below in Python's cx_Oracle module.

```
import cx_Oracle

db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect("user/user123@dbhost:1521/db1")
db_cur = db_conn.cursor()

db_cur.execute("create table emp (empid number, empname varchar2(100))")
```

I want to get that "Table Created" output (from above db_conn or db_cur may be) which would have displayed if I executed this statement in command line like below.

```
SQL> create table emp (empid number, empname varchar2(100));

Table created.
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I searched a lot in google and Oracle's documentation for this and I was not able find any particular (not even closer to this topic) discussion or articles on this.

Comment: Currently there is no way of identifying this message in cx_Oracle (which is essentially using OCI). I am saying this because I don't want someone search for the feature which is currently not implemented. Oracle cx_Oracle team took this as next enhancement for cx_Oracle. Ref: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/468